# Getting error object has no attribute 'get' while using clean in django modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to custom validate my model form. For the purpose, I wrote the following code:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):

        batch_start_year = self.cleaned_data.get('batch_start_year',None)
```

I am getting error like:

```
'StudentForm' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I tried another solution, but it didn't work either.

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(StudentForm, self).clean()

        batch_start_year = cleaned_data['batch_start_year']
```

Please help me to solve this.

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/shahjahan/Desktop/jmialumniusa/jmialumniusa_app/views.py", line 18, in apply
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 161, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 153, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 364, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 377, in _post_clean
    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 337, in _get_validation_exclusions
    field_value = self.cleaned_data.get(field)
AttributeError: 'StudentForm' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Did you get same error for both method you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You should return cleaned data from `clean()` method or raise error. You are not doing that.

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        batch_start_year = self.cleaned_data.get('batch_start_year',None)
        # do something
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate all your form, you can use clean method like this

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(StudentForm, self).clean()
        batch_start_year = cleaned_data.get('batch_start_year')
```

In this case, you do not need to return anything. You will just raise validation error. If you want to validate some specific field, you will do it like this

```
def clean_field_name(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data.get('field_name')
    if "something" not in data:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Validation message")

    # Always return the cleaned data, whether you have changed it or
    # not.
    return data
```

Another possibility of error can be the way you are sending data to your form

```
student = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
form = StudentForm(intention) # An unbound form
```

The first argument to a form is the data but you are passing the instance. To properly pass the instance you should use:

```
student = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
form = StudentForm(instance=student) #
```